# Hibernate cross-field validation for integers?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-validator

I'd like to perform cross-field `hibernate` validation on the following class:

```
public class MyClass {
        private int adults;
        private int children;

        @Range(min = 0, max = 4)
        private int getPersons() {
            return adults + children;
        }
}
```

Result: "HV000090: Unable to access getPersons."

Why can't I make validations on a method that does not have an explicit class member variable?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why is `getPersons()` private? Why is the return type `Integer` if it never can be null? How did you define your entity, are you using field or property access?

Comment: I only created this method for validation purpose. That's why it's private, as it should never be accessed. `Integer` was a typo, sorry.

Comment: yes private getter, because as I wrote it should not be accessed, but hibernate can only find getters or setters.

Comment: It should work. Could you post the full stacktrace? Also how are you triggering validation and which version of Hibernate Validator are you using? Besides of that, I probably would use a custom class level constraints instead of introducing a private method which is not used for anything (except validation).

Comment: Ok you're probably right, I will go for the classlevle contraints.

Answer (score 0):

I never used Hibernate Validator, but from what I read, validation only works on public properties (as opposed to field based validation where access type doesn't seem to matter), i.e. HV can't access `getPersons()` since it is private. Changing that to public should resolve the issue.

Comment: No, hibernate does not need public methods. For example, try `@AssertTrue private boolean test() { return false; }`, which causes the validator to always fail.

Comment: @membersound is this true for getters/setters, i.e. property accessors as well? Your example wouldn't be an accessor method.

Comment: Sorry, I ment to write `getTest();`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Range(min = 0, max = 4)
    private int getPersons() {
  if(Objects.nonNull(adults)
  && Objects.nonNull(children))){
        return adults+children;
      }
     return Objects.nonNull(adults) ? abults: children;
    }
```